# Flask-Docker container not responding if I change the internal port from 5000

Tags: docker, flask, containers

I am using the [following tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dockerize-a-flask-app/) to learn the basics of Dockerizing a Flask Application.

When I follow the tutorial exactly it works and I can connect to the container via curl or browser.

By following the tutorial I mean that I use the following app.run line in the code and the following docker run commands:

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
docker run -d --name flask-date-app -p 5000:5000 flask-date
```

I can change the port used by changing just the docker run command as follows:

```
docker run -d --name flask-date-app -p 5001:5000 flask-date
```

What doesn't work is changing the port inside the app.run command:

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001, debug=True)
docker run -d --name flask-date-app -p 5001:5001 flask-date
```

As I have shown in the second example, I can get around the port issue by just changing the "docker run" command but I am curious why this isn't working when I change the port inside the Flask application.

Thanks for any insight into what  I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is the `CMD` in your Dockerfile?  (Are you starting the Flask application via some other path, like a GUnicorn server, that wouldn't necessarily honor the `app.run()` call?)

Comment: I'm using the following run command in my Docker file:

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

Should I just add "--port=5001" to the CMD entry?  I figured the app.run command was already taking care of that.